# what data-type to use to store MAC addresses in an SQL Server database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to store MAC addresses in one of my database tables, what data-type should I use? Reading articles on google, I have seen Binary(8) mentioned a few times. Is this the correct way?

Also, this does not make sense to me, as MAC addresses are six groups of two hexadecimal digits, wouldn't you use Binary(6)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Binary` at all.

I would use `CHAR(12)`.

Though this really depends on what you use the data for - if this is for display only, you can simply use the textual representation.

Comment: Why? What is the benefit? This table will have ~1 million mac address entries. I will be handing out MAC addresses to devices that are missing them and already deployed in the field.

Comment: @Mausimo - Well, what is the purpose of having these? Display only? What's the benefit in having them in `Binary`?

Comment: I am not sure what the benefit is. I need to populate a table with our MAC Address block and then hand them out to devices when they connect to an application. I have seen Binary(8) mentioned in a few posts, so I figured that was a good starting point.

Comment: @Mausimo - If you need to query on these (i.e finding MAC addresses using parts of the address), you could use bitwise operations to get them - in such a case, it would make sense to store them in `Binary`. Otherwise, keep them readable.

Comment: @Mausimo - I'll say it again. It really depends on the needs of the application.

Comment: I pretty much, just need to associate a mac address with an object and then get the next available mac address and associate it with the next object. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @mausimo, i ask you to please take Oded's advice. Storing them as Binary, even across 5M rows, would only save you 20MB of disk space. So, for the trade off you get much more complex queries and much less query performance when trying to find the next available to lease. Don't strain a gnat to swallow a camel.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use char(12)

Answer (score 5):

For easier performaing binary operations you can store them into Binary(6)
You can use the following built in function to view the Hex readable value of the binary data:

```
select top 10 master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(mac) from macaddresses
```

and to convert the hexadecimal text into binary:

```
select CONVERT(binary(6), 'AABBCCDDEEFF', 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

MAC address is a sequence of 6 hexadecimal numbers. That's why it would be efficient to store it as a number. Use BIGINT.